# copy files from directory/subdirectory listed in text file (Mac)

Tags: macos, command-line, file-transfer

I'm looking to search and then copy all files with filenames matching in a text file from a directory (with subdirectories) on a server to another directory. I've found a great solution (though quite slow) for windows [here](http://www.sidesofmarch.com/index.php/archive/2004/03/30/using-the-for-command-to-copy-files-listed-in-a-text-file/).

in a .bat file, something like:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (text-list.txt) do echo D|xcopy "\\SERVER\FOLDER\%%i?" "c:\temp" /i /z /y /s
```

How can I accomplish this on Mac/Linux?

this works for files that are all in the same directory, but I can't figure out how to search subdirectories within the source folder:

```
rsync --files-from ~/filelist.txt . ~/destfolder
```

based on the example from @neofug, this is a perl script to do this. it works well except that it does not search through the subfolders in the srcfolder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
my $textFile = shift @ARGV;
my $filenames = {};
open F1, "<", $textFile or die "Cannot open file $textFile! $!\n";
while ( <F1> ){
  chomp;
  $filenames->{$_}++;
}
close(F1);
my $imgDir = "/Users/username/srcfolder";
chdir($imgDir);
my @imgList = glob "*.txt";
foreach(@imgList){
  if($filenames->{$_}){
    system("/bin/cp $_ /Users/username/destfolder");
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, I've been trying with rsync. I've included that example above now.

Comment: See if this this article is any help to you - showcases how to use the "find" and "rsync" command in sync - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87018/find-and-rysnc

Answer (score 1):

You can us [perl](https://www.perl.org/) to accomplish this, enter the text file list as a command line argument and change the paths to suit your setup:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env perl
    use strict;
    use File::Find;
    my $textFile = shift @ARGV;
    my $filenames = {};
    open F1, "<", $textFile or die "Cannot open file $textFile! $!\n";
    while ( <F1> ){
      chomp;
      $filenames->{$_}++;
    }
    close(F1);
    my $imgDir = "/home/user/Pictures/";
    my $imgList = {};
    find(\&findPics, "/home/user/Pictures/");
    foreach(keys %$imgList){
      if($filenames->{$_}){
        system("/bin/cp $imgList->{$_} /path/to/newImages/");
      }
    }
    sub findPics{
      if($_ =~ /.+[jpg|jpeg|png|gif]/i){
        $imgList->{$_} = $File::Find::name;
      }
    }
```

Edit: I modified this program as requested by the op to recurse within the given directory to find all images.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't used perl before, but that is a great solution. It works for me except that doesn't search through subfolders in the srcfolder. I've added the bit above modified from your example. Any idea on how to make it search recursively? Thanks!